# Deleting a row in an array based on the smallest value in anther array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I am using python-3.x, , and I have searched about the following error but could not find the correct solution.

the Error is:

```
IndexError: index 9 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 9'
```

So what I am doing is creating random binary array “binary” also a random numbers array “value” and I want to delete the lowest two rows in the binary array based on the (index) for the smallest two values in the  “value” array.

as I know I am accessing outside the bounds of an array but what is the right way to solve this error?

**So in my code, where is the problem and how can solve it Any help would be highly appreciated**

```
import random
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.nan)


for i in range (100):


    binary= np.random.randint (2, size=(10, 4))
    print("binary:" '\n',binary)


    value = np.random.randint (200, size=(10, 1))
    print("value:" '\n',value)




    for i in range (2):
#       the loseer how have the of the binarys who has the smaslets value 
        loser = np.argmin(value)
#        print ("loser:",loser)
#        print("loser:", loser,(value[loser]))
#        print (binary[loser,])
#        print("Loser=", "Index:", loser,"value:",(value[loser]), "binary:",(binary[loser,]))
        print("Index:", loser)
        print("value:",(value[loser]))
        print("binary:",(binary[loser,]))
        print("Loser=", "Index:", loser,"value:",(value[loser]), "binary:",(binary[loser,]))



        binary = np.delete(binary, (loser), axis=0)
        print("binary:" '\n',binary)
```

In this code, I used **np.argmin** because I don't want to use sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is that after the first iteration in `for i in range (2)`, you deleted an element from `binary` but not from `value`. Hence these arrays are not of the same length anymore, and the indices in both of them are not consistent. In addition, by doing `loser = np.argmin(value)` in both iterations, you are just finding the same minimal value twice, not the 2 smallest.

Instead, you can do the following:

```
binary= np.random.randint (2, size=(10, 4))
value = np.random.randint (200, size=(10, 1))

ind = np.argpartition(-value.T[0], -2)[-2:]
binary=np.delete(binary,ind,0)
```

unlike sorting, [np.argpartition](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html) runs in linear time, using [Introselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introselect). It finds the indices of `k` largest elements (not in sorted order). I did

```
-value.T[0]
```

because you wanted the 2 smallest elements, and I also reshaped `value` to a `1D` array to input it into `np.argpartition`.